# For an order 3 square matrix A, whose characteristic polynomial is $c^3-3c^2+4= 0$, find trace of adjoint A

Tags: linear-algebra

For an order 3 square matrix A, whose characteristic polynomial
is $c^3-3c^2+4= 0$, find the trace of its adjoint A.

I know using Jacobi we have a relation and i can get the answer.

But can there be a simpler explanation for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "using Jacobi"?

Comment: Is the matrix complex valued?

Comment: Does "adjoint" here mean "adjugate" or "conjugate transpose"?

Comment: @RobertLewis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula

Comment: Note that $c^3-3c^2+4=(c+1)(c^2-4(c-1))=(c+1)(c-2)^2$ so that you can also calculate the eigenvalue expressions directly.

Comment: what do i do after calculating eigen values?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Denoting by $A^*$ the adjoint, you know that

$$A A^*= \det(A) I_n=-4 I_n$$

Therefore, 
$$A^*=-4A^{-1}$$

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Then, the eigenvalues of $A^\star$ are 
$$\beta_i=-\frac{4}{\lambda_i}$$

So you need to calculate 
$$\mbox{tr}(A^*)=\frac{-4}{\lambda_1}+\frac{-4}{\lambda_2}+\frac{-4}{\lambda_3}=\frac{-4(\lambda_2 \lambda_3+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_1\lambda_2)}{\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3}$$
which you can get from the coefficients of your polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the characteristic polynomial of a 3 by 3 matrix $A$ is given by $$\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^3-\lambda^2\operatorname{tr}(A)+\lambda k-\det(A)$$
for some constant $k$. In your case we thus have $\operatorname{tr}(A)=3$ and therefore also $\operatorname{tr}(A^*)=3$.

Comment: If $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ your argument shows that $A^*= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ has $tr(A^*)=1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065822/305862

Comment: @N.S. Why is the adjoint the zero matrix? I think you mean the adjugate matrix.

Comment: @Nightgap In linear algebra Adjoint typically means cofactor transpose... Also given the comment about using Jacobi, this is what the OP likely menas. You are thinking about the other meaning of adjoint.